# Cannot resolve method 'feed' while using TensorflowInterfenceInterface methods

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am implementing TensorFlowInferenceInterface in my android project. But I found the Cannot resolve method 'feed(java.lang.String, java.lang.reflect.Array, long, java.lang.long,java.lang.long,?) error. How can I solve it?

```
import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;
.......

private TensorFlowInferenceInterface tensorFlowInference;
.......
tensorFlowInference.feed(inputName, imageNormalizedPixels,1L, imageSize, imageSize, COLOR_CHANNELS.toLong())
```

I cannot implement the methods of TensorFlowInferenceInterface such as feed, run, fetch.

Comment: Post your Interface code also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem which attach importance to parameter types.

Before I solved my problem, my `pixelArray` is `float[][]` because I thought it is an image. When I used:

```
inferenceInterface.feed(INPUTNAME, pixelArray,  1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1);
```

I got:

> Cannot resolve method 'feed(java.lang.String, float[][], int, int, int, int)'

Then I made `pixelArray` be `float[]`, the problem was gone.

I use `float` input as an example, notice that the method feed is `public void feed(String inputName, float[] src, long... dims)`. But in your code, the `COLOR_CHANNELS.toLong()` corresponding to "?" in what you got, and `imageNormalizedPixels` corresponding to `java.lang.reflect.Array`.

I found a description about `java.lang.reflect.Array`: "It creates arrays based on multi-dimensional arrays, and one-dimensional arrays are only special implementations."

So I thought your `imageNormalizedPixels` probably  isn't a 1-D array.